# Elisp function to see a date for next Wednesday

Tags: time-date, parsing

Admitting up front that I am not capable of much Lisp, I have found ways to produce the current date or a number of seconds from a date, but I am looking for a simple equivalent to shell command like `date -d "next wed"` I believe that with the output fed to `(format-time-string ...` I can get what I need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Emacs's built-in date parser is `parse-time-string` in [`parse-time.el`](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/emacs-24/annotate/head:/lisp/calendar/parse-time.el), called by [`date-to-time`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Time-Parsing.html#index-date_002dto_002dtime-4157). It understands English month and weekday names and several combinations of elements in various orders, but not expressions like “next Wednesday”.

The [date input formats](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Date-input-formats) in the GNU `date` command provided on non-embedded Linux and Cygwin are implemented in the source of the `date` utility, they are not available as a standalone library.

If the GNU `date` utility is available on your system, you can call it. The following snippet returns a time parsed by `date` as a list (SEC MIN HOUR DAY MON YEAR DOW DST TZ).

```
(let ((human-time "next Wednesday"))
  (parse-time-string (with-temp-buffer
                       (call-process "env" nil t nil "LC_ALL=C" "LANGUAGE=" "date" "-d" human-time)
                       (or (bobp) (delete-backward-char 1))
                       (buffer-string)))
```

Comment: Extremely helpful! I was thinking that I was just missing some internal call that might use the same function style as _localtime()_ would.

Comment: @Gilles I am curious why you used `env`. This also works: `(call-process "date" nil t nil "-d" human-time)`.

Comment: @KaushalModi This only works if your environment specifies the US date format. Otherwise the output of `date` is not something `parse-time-string` understands.

Answer (score 4):

I made an Elisp only solution:

You can call it using `M-x dow-time` and in code using `(dow-time 3)`

```
(defvar dow-time-days '(("Monday" . 1)
                        ("Tuesday" . 2)
                        ("Wednesday" . 3)
                        ("Thursday" . 4)
                        ("Friday" . 5)
                        ("Saturday" . 6)
                        ("Sunday" . 0))
  "Days of week alist used by `dow-time'")

(defun dow-time (day-input)
  "Get time for next day of week, 0 is Sunday
Also accepts human readable strings"
  (interactive (list
                (completing-read "Day of week: " dow-time-days nil t)))
  (let* ((day (if (numberp day-input) day-input
                (cdr (assoc day-input dow-time-days))))
         (time (decode-time))
         (dow (nth 6 time))
         (day-of-month (nth 3 time))
         (new-dow (if (> day dow)        ; Check what's the new dow's index
                       (- day dow)       ; In the same week
                     (+ (- 7 dow) day))) ; In the next week
         (new-time (encode-time 0 0 0
                                (+ new-dow day-of-month)
                                (nth 4 time)
                                (nth 5 time))))
    (if (called-interactively-p 'any)
        (message (current-time-string new-time)) ; Print nicely if interactive
      new-time)))
```

Comment: This is more precisely what I asked after, but doesn't address the bigger picture of handling more generic "adjust" function (c.f. **BSD** _-v_) or the _-d_ functionality in the `localtime` call. It is extremely helpful in my case though.